# Trademark used only for profit motive / trademark not the right solution?

Tags: trademark

My daughter is starting a podcast. It will have a focused theme, say for example "Artists against Racism." (Note: this is not the topic, just a similar type of example). Now the purpose of the blog will be to interview artists, with a focus on how art can be used to help people join together, etc.
When I went to see about trademarking the Podcast title, the application seemed focused on the income the trademark is looking to protect. This...

[image]

To me, the purpose of the trademark would be to protect her from investing her time, potentially years of it, and then getting a DCMA or similar notice that someone trademarked the name for a similar, profit driven, business.

The question is - Is a trademark not suitable for this purpose? And, if not, what would one use to protect the entity and her work?

(And, as I write this, and reflect, a fix might very well be that we also buy a nice logo, and just offer to sell some simple items, shirts and coffee mugs (?), and then I proceed to spend some money to show she has income from the podcast. I'm open to this, but it seems disingenuous.)

Please ask questions in comments if I missed any appropriate detail.

Comment: Will do. I wasn’t thinking of that as it’s not a charity, but that might be a good start. Much thanks.

Comment: You might google "trademark nonprofit". Many many nonprofits have trademarked names - United Way among them  - no need to do anything disingenuous.

Comment: You've set me on the right path, thanks, again. Her mission is 'good' but not quite a charity, and not a 'nonprofit', but I can already see the search on this yielding good results. I was stuck in a certain way of thinking, and this helped me get on a better path.